# Python - Error: SQLCODE=-30082r] SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID"). SQLSTATE=08001

Tags: python, sql, db2

Olá!
Preciso de ajuda para o seguinte problema:
Fiz um script em python para coletar dados de uma tabela DB2 e gerar uma planilha.
Estou na fase de testes, mas a ideia é que o script executará sozinho todos os dias.
Entretanto, nesta semana a senha de acesso a tabela expirou e uma nova senha foi gerada. Mas essa senha contém o carácter `;` e por causa dele o meu script parou de funcionar.
Quando o script chega nesta função:

```py
def connect_db2(self, data_base, hostname, port, username, password):
    try:
        connection = ibm_db.connect(f"DATABASE={data_base};HOSTNAME={hostname};\
        PORT={port}; PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={username};PWD={password};", "", "")
        return connection
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

ocorre o erro do título:

> `SQLCODE=-30082r] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24"("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001`

Eu sei que é por causa do `;` pois testei o acesso direto na tabela e funciona, somente não funciona no script.

Na época que ocorreu o problema pela primeira vez alteramos a senha e funcionou para os testes. Agora, estou prestes a colocar em produção e novamente ocorre o problema.

Eu não quero ter que solicitar a pessoa responsável pelo acesso a verificar a senha antes de atualizar para o script não parar de funcionar, já que se trata de uma automação.

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma forma de o script/função aceitar o `;` como parte da senha.

Comment: força o escape do carater: \;

Answer (score 0):

vc tentou usar o delimitador de string do DB2 em torno da string do password ?

```
connection = ibm_db.connect(f"DATABASE={data_base};HOSTNAME={hostname};PORT={port};\PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID={username};PWD='{password}';", "", "")
```

Não tenho certeza, se for aspas duplas ('"') ao invés do que está no meu exemplo,
tente usar aspas simples na string python ...  mas tente a primeira antes de inverter tudo

> Also these workaround won't help outside db2prompt for example: db2
> connect to sample USER admin USING '!xyz' SQL0104N An unexpected token
> "!" was found following "". Expected tokens may include: "NEW".
> SQLSTATE=42601

fonte: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/usernamepassword-special-characters-need-be-quoted-when-using-them-through-clp-within-db2prompt-iedb2

Acho que não vai rolar alguns caracteres 8(

Comment: Ola! Testei com aspas duplas e simples, mesmo erro. Ele e entende que quando :( ...

Comment: Cheguei a colocar esta linha de comando : password.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict') , mas foi a mesma coisa...

Comment: password.encode não faz sentido pra mim. 
Este erro não é do Python, 
é no DB2 ou do conector de DB2 que está usando. por isso falei de adiconar o delimitador de string e somente no passowrd

Comment: Sim, eu coloquei o delimitador somente no password. O problema é que quando o valor da password é lida, o ; é entendido como outro parametro, por isso da o erro referente a senha. Eu testei a senha para acessar as tabelas diretamente no DB2 e esta funcionando.

Comment: da uma olhada ...   estou sem opções 8( 
mas da uma olhada aqui ve se descobre algo  
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/usernamepassword-special-characters-need-be-quoted-when-using-them-through-clp-within-db2prompt-iedb2

Comment: De boas :) ! Eu vou olhar sim, mas de qualquer forma muito obrigada :D!